# Excel small formula not returing small value due to duplicate value

Tags: excel, array-formulas, vba

I got struck in Array formula. Assume, my Range has Value like

```
A1:F1 = {1,0,2,1,0,3}.
```

I want to use one array formula dynamically to find value as 1st small as `0`, 2nd Small as `1,3rd as 2 and 4th as 3`.

`Formula =Small(A1:F1,k)` gives second small as 0. Whereas I wanted to have 1 as second by excluding duplicate small value 0.

Any formula to remove duplicate would be helpful. I tried this one, `SMALL(IF(A1:F1>SMALL(A1:F1,k),A1:F1,""),k)` , here `k` represent n'th small value, It gives me wrong output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found solution, however I don't know how to clearly describe this composition of formulas, so I [have uploaded it](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tfjbfju2o0j39aa/Manish%20example.xlsx?dl=0) as an example. Please download and check if it is what you need. The column A is column with data, column B is list of min values, column C is number of this min values in column with data.